# How to insert text with HTML Code with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have some data in my MySQL with HTML code.

### Example:

```
<b>William Shakespeare</b> was an English poet.
```

I need to insert this text into a Vue.js Component.

My code is:

```
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(MY API)
      .then(response => (this.author = response.data))
      .catch(error => error("error"));
  }
```

And then:

```
<p class="card-text">
    {{author.description}}
</p>
```

The problem is the tags into the description aren't interpreted and it shows the HTML tags.

Comment: v-html directive

Comment: Use v-html directive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) directive on your parapraph:

```html
<p class="card-text" v-html="author.description" />
```

**But BE VERY CAREFUL about the possibility of XSS attack if `author.description` is going to contain user provided data.**

Comment: Thanks, Orkhan Alikhanov. Data comes from a JSON API made from a MySQL view.

Comment: My warning is about who inserts the data into the database. Because if the plain html is inserted by user, then he can, instead of `<p>William...`, insert `<script>/// malicious code...` and that malicious code will be run every time in a user's browser visiting the page that renders it with v-html. That malicious script can do anything on behalf of the user

Comment: Thanks, Orkhan Alikhanov. I understood what you meant. Contents are made by me.