# how to render the html dynamically in vue

Tags: vue.js

a vue code below will load a html dynamically and I want to render this part of html into GUI. how would I do this?

```
<template>

</template>

<script>
import request from '@/utils/request';
export default {
        name: 'Personalinforadm',
        data() {
            return {
              html:''
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.loadHtml();
        },
        methods: {
            loadHtml(){
                request({ url: '/page/html', method: 'get'})
                .then(resp => {
                    this.html = resp.data;
                    this.renderHtml();
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                }); 
            },
            renderHtml(){
               // how to render the html into the UI
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert text with HTML Code with Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670357/how-to-insert-text-with-html-code-with-vue-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<template>
  <div v-html='html' />
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import request from '@/utils/request';
export default {
        name: 'Personalinforadm',
        data() {
            return {
              html:''
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.loadHtml();
        },
        methods: {
            loadHtml(){
                request({ url: '/page/html', method: 'get'})
                .then(resp => {
                    this.html = resp.data;
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                }); 
            },
           
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using `v-html` as follows:

```html
<template>
  <div v-html="html"></div>
</template>

<script>
  import request from '@/utils/request';
  export default {
    name: 'Personalinforadm',
    data() {
      return {
        html:''
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.loadHtml();
    },
    methods: {
      loadHtml() {
        request({ url: '/page/html', method: 'get'})
          .then(resp => {
            this.html = resp.data;
          }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          }); 
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

As you can see, you don't need a `renderHtml` method at all, as vue does the work for you.

*By the way: I recommend you to use async/await instead of `.then`. It in my opinion makes your code cleaner and look more professional.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried v-html?

Documentation: https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#HTML

Comment: Please take a look at the other answers, submitted around the same time, for good examples of how to recommend a technique. Instead of just asking if they've tried a control, instead show them how they can solve their specific problem by offering additional context. Ideally, supplement it with an explanation as well so they can learn the concepts behind the code.

Comment: Ok, next time i'll write a best answer, thanks for your tip!