# Vue unable to parse template literal when string contains HTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Please see this example:

```js
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    code() {
      return `<script src="https://js.example.com/app.js" async></script>`;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ code }}</div>
</template>
```

This code is reporting error, How can I solve this?

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/awesome-farrell-d5kc8n)

Comment: See [How to insert text with HTML Code with Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670357/how-to-insert-text-with-html-code-with-vue-js) and apparently [Loading a JavaScript script dynamically in a Vue.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007508/loading-a-javascript-script-dynamically-in-a-vue-js-app)